# Show form inside a table using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, html-table

I have a table with various rows. Each row contain item description and a link to order the item. I now need to show a form below that row when the link is clicked.

I could accomplish it by using multiple forms for each table row and using the Jquery `hide()` and `show()` function. But that dont seem much logical.

Is there a better way. Like I could create the form at only one place and call it when the link is clicked and it is displayed below the table row.

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td> The Item Description </td>
  <td><a href=""> Order now </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <!-- the form should be here , it should be initially hidden but must be displayed when the link is clicked. I will have a huge number of Items -->
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Will the row containing the form always come directly after the row containing the item description and order now link?

Comment: no.. It should be there, just below the first row, when the ordernow link is clicked

Comment: I don't see any problem with it. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CjFIf

Comment: @Shanimal .. well as i have stated in the question, I can do it your way, using the form below every row. But I dont want it that way. I want to create the form at one place, and then use the link to call it below every row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function to populate the form, yes.

```
function populate(description, quantity) {
  $('#myForm').show();
  $('#description', '#myForm').val(description);
  $('#quantity', '#myForm').val(quantity);
}
```

and you should bind that function to the onclick event

```
$('a.order').click(function(){
  var desc = $('.description', $(this)).text(),
      quan = $('.quantity', $(this)).text();
  populate(desc,quan);
  $('#myForm').insertAfter($(this).parent()); // to 'move' the form after the <td> parent of <a>
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Don't forget a `return false;` in the click function.

Answer (score 2):

My version. I store form hidden and just append it to the temporary row:

```
var $form  = $('.form'),
    $table = $('.table');

$table.on('click', '.link', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $table.find('tr.temp-row').remove();
    $(this).closest('tr').after(function() {
        var $tr = $('<tr class="temp-row"><td colspan="4"></td></tr>');
        return $tr.find('td').html($form).end();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3XWUz/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to each order button, then when one of those is clicked it toggles the for `tr`

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td> The Item Description </td>
  <td><a href="" class="order"> Order now </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> The Item Description </td>
  <td><a href="" class="order"> Order now </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> The Item Description </td>
  <td><a href="" class="order"> Order now </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> The Item Description </td>
  <td><a href="" class="order"> Order now </td>
</tr>
<tr id="form_tr" style="display: none;">
  <td colspan="2">
  <!-- the form should be here , it should be initially hidden but must be displayed when the link is clicked. I will have a huge number of Items -->
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.order').click(function() {
  $('#form_tr').toggle();
    return false;
});
```

You'll need to add in more code to update the form with the correct product, but that's the general idea.

Comment: He wants to display the form beneath each option, not simply at the end of the table.

Comment: ya your code will only display the form in the end of the table, after the last row. I need it below each row, when the order now button is clicked.

Comment: Ah, I misread the question. I thought you were asking to show the form in one place no matter which link you clicked.